# Infinite looping Issue Python. Can't quit game

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I made a code for Blackjack in Python and whenever I run blackjack_game(deck) saying no to the 'Play Again' input should quit the game but it doesn't. Funds going zero and below should also trigger the game to quit but it doesn't.

This is what it looks like:

```
import random
import os


 
# The Card class definition
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value, card_value):
         
        # Suit of the Card like Spades and Clubs
        self.suit = suit
 
        # Representing Value of the Card like A for Ace, K for King
        self.value = value
 
        # Score Value for the Card like 10 for King
        self.card_value = card_value




# Clear the terminal
def clear():
    os.system("clear")

# Print player stats
def print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts):
    print('Player: ', player_name)
    print('Funds: $', funds)
    print(f'Wins: {wins} Losses: {losses} Ties: {ties} Blackjacks: {blackjacks} Busts: {busts}')

# Function to print the cards
def print_cards(cards, hidden):
         
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t ________________"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t ________________"
    print(s)
 
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|                |"    
    print(s)
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        if card.value == '10':
            s = s + "\t|  {}            |".format(card.value)
        else:
            s = s + "\t|  {}             |".format(card.value)  
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|                |"    
    print(s)
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|      * *       |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|    *     *     |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|   *       *    |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|   *       *    |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|       {}        |".format(card.suit)
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|          *     |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|         *      |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|        *       |"
    print(s)
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|                |"
    print(s)
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|                |"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|                |"
    print(s)    
 
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        if card.value == '10':
            s = s + "\t|            {}  |".format(card.value)
        else:
            s = s + "\t|            {}   |".format(card.value)
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|        *       |"        
    print(s)    
         
    s = ""
    for card in cards:
        s = s + "\t|________________|"
    if hidden:
        s += "\t|________________|"
    print(s)        
 
    print()
 
 
# Function for a game of blackjack
def blackjack_game(deck):
    end_game = False
    play_again = 'Y'

    # Player name
    player_name = str(input('Enter player name: '))

    # Intro
    print('Lets have a fun game of Blackjack, ', player_name)
    
    # Cards for both dealer and player
    player_cards = []
    dealer_cards = []
 
    # Scores for both dealer and player
    player_score = 0
    dealer_score = 0

    # Player stats
    funds = 100
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    ties = 0
    blackjacks = 0
    busts = 0

    bet = 0

    clear()

    # Current Stats Display
    print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)

    # Bets
    while play_again == 'Y':
     while end_game == False:
      while funds > 0:
       while bet == 0:
        bet = int(input('Enter bet amount: '))

        if bet > funds:
         print('Insufficient funds')
         bet = 0
 
       # Initial dealing for player and dealer
       while len(player_cards) < 2:
 
        # Randomly dealing a card
        player_card = random.choice(deck)
        player_cards.append(player_card)
        deck.remove(player_card)
 
        # Updating the player score
        player_score += player_card.card_value
 
        # In case both the cards are Ace, make the first ace value as 1 
        if len(player_cards) == 2:
            if player_cards[0].card_value == 11 and player_cards[1].card_value == 11:
                player_cards[0].card_value = 1
                player_score -= 10
 
        # Print player cards and score      
        print("PLAYER CARDS: ")
        print_cards(player_cards, False)
        print("PLAYER SCORE = ", player_score)
 
        input()
 
        # Randomly dealing a card
        dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
        dealer_cards.append(dealer_card)
        deck.remove(dealer_card)
 
        # Updating the dealer score
        dealer_score += dealer_card.card_value
 
        # Print dealer cards and score, keeping in mind to hide the second card and score
        print("DEALER CARDS: ")
        if len(dealer_cards) == 1:
            print_cards(dealer_cards, False)
            print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score)
        else:
            print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)    
            print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)
 
 
        # In case both the cards are Ace, make the second ace value as 1 
        if len(dealer_cards) == 2:
            if dealer_cards[0].card_value == 11 and dealer_cards[1].card_value == 11:
                dealer_cards[1].card_value = 1
                dealer_score -= 10
 
        input()


       clear()
 
       # Print dealer and player cards
       print("DEALER CARDS: ")
       print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
       print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)
 
       print() 
 
       print("PLAYER CARDS: ")
       print_cards(player_cards, False)
       print("PLAYER SCORE = ", player_score)
      
 
       # Managing the player moves
       while player_score < 21:
        choice = input("Enter H to Hit or S to Stand : ")
 
        # Sanity checks for player's choice
        if len(choice) != 1 or (choice.upper() != 'H' and choice.upper() != 'S'):
            clear()
            print("Wrong choice!! Try Again")
 
        # If player decides to HIT
        if choice.upper() == 'H':
 
            # Dealing a new card
            player_card = random.choice(deck)
            player_cards.append(player_card)
            deck.remove(player_card)
 
            # Updating player score
            player_score += player_card.card_value
 
            # Updating player score in case player's card have ace in them
            c = 0
            while player_score > 21 and c < len(player_cards):
                if player_cards[c].card_value == 11:
                    player_cards[c].card_value = 1
                    player_score -= 10
                    c += 1
                else:
                    c += 1 
 
            clear()     
 
            # Print player and dealer cards
            print("DEALER CARDS: ")
            print_cards(dealer_cards[:-1], True)
            print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score - dealer_cards[-1].card_value)
 
            print()
 
            print("PLAYER CARDS: ")
            print_cards(player_cards, False)
            print("PLAYER SCORE = ", player_score)
             
        # If player decides to Stand
        if choice.upper() == 'S':
            break
 
 
       clear() 
 
       # Print player and dealer cards
       print("PLAYER CARDS: ")
       print_cards(player_cards, False)
       print("PLAYER SCORE = ", player_score)
 
       print()
       print("DEALER IS REVEALING THE CARDS....")
 
       print("DEALER CARDS: ")
       print_cards(dealer_cards, False)
       print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score)
 
       # Check if player has a Blackjack
       if player_score == 21:
        print("PLAYER HAS A BLACKJACK")
        blackjacks += 1
        
 
       # Check if player busts
       if player_score > 21:
        print("PLAYER BUSTED!!!")
        busts += 1
        print("DEALER WINS!!!")
        losses += 1
        funds -= bet
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True
 
       input() 
 
       # Managing the dealer moves
       while dealer_score < 17:
        clear() 
 
        print("DEALER DECIDES TO HIT.....")
 
        # Dealing card for dealer
        dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
        dealer_cards.append(dealer_card)
        deck.remove(dealer_card)
 
        # Updating the dealer's score
        dealer_score += dealer_card.card_value
 
        # Updating player score in case player's card have ace in them
        c = 0
        while dealer_score > 21 and c < len(dealer_cards):
            if dealer_cards[c].card_value == 11:
                dealer_cards[c].card_value = 1
                dealer_score -= 10
                c += 1
            else:
                c += 1
 
        # print player and dealer cards
        print("PLAYER CARDS: ")
        print_cards(player_cards, False)
        print("PLAYER SCORE = ", player_score)
 
        print()
 
        print("DEALER CARDS: ")
        print_cards(dealer_cards, False)
        print("DEALER SCORE = ", dealer_score)      
 
        input()
 
       # TIE Game
       if dealer_score == player_score:
        print("TIE GAME!!!!")
        ties += 1
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True
      
       # Dealer busts
       elif dealer_score > 21:        
        print("DEALER BUSTED!!! YOU WIN!!!") 
        wins += 1
        funds += bet
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True
 
       # Dealer gets a blackjack
       elif dealer_score == 21:
        print("DEALER HAS A BLACKJACK!!! PLAYER LOSES")
        losses += 1
        funds -= bet
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True
 
       # Player Wins
       elif player_score < 21 and player_score > dealer_score:
        print("PLAYER WINS!!!")
        wins += 1
        funds += bet
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True                 
 
       # Dealer Wins
       else:
        print("DEALER WINS!!!")
        losses += 1
        funds -= bet
        bet = 0
        print_stats(player_name, funds, wins, losses, ties, blackjacks, busts)
        end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
        play_again = end_choice.upper()
        player_cards = []
        dealer_cards = []
        player_score = 0
        dealer_score = 0
        end_game = True               

    quit()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # The type of suit
    suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
 
    # The suit value 
    suits_values = {"Spades":"\u2664", "Hearts":"\u2661", "Clubs": "\u2667", "Diamonds": "\u2662"}
 
    # The type of card
    cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
 
    # The card value
    cards_values = {"A": 11, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}
 
    # The deck of cards
    deck = []
 
    # Loop for every type of suit
    for suit in suits:
 
        # Loop for every type of card in a suit
        for card in cards:
 
            # Adding card to the deck
            deck.append(Card(suits_values[suit], card, cards_values[card]))
```

I added a quit() that should trigger should 'while play_again == 'Y':' no longer be true. This should have quit the game and stopped it from running. Instead it prompts the user again for a betting amount, acting as if I chose 'Y' instead.

I also tried removing:

```
play_again = 'Y'
```

and replacing this code block:

```
end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
play_again = end_choice.upper()
```

with this:

```
end_choice = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
if end_choice.upper() == 'N':
 exit()
```

But it still wouldn't quit and stayed as an infinite loop. Help me please, I've been stuck with this issue all day.

Comment: 400+ lines of code... I ran it, and nothing happened. If you hope to get a useful answer, reduce the code to 50 lines, removing anything that is not contributing to the problem you have. This code-trimming exercise might even lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try by replacing from this:

```
    # Bets
    while play_again == 'Y':
        while end_game == False:
            while funds > 0:
                while bet == 0:
                    bet = int(input('Enter bet amount: '))

                    if bet > funds:
                        print('Insufficient funds')
                        bet = 0
```

With

```
    # Bets
    while play_again == 'Y':
        while end_game == False:
            if play_again != 'Y':
                break
            while funds > 0:
                if play_again != 'Y' or end_game:
                    break
                while bet == 0:
                    bet = int(input('Enter bet amount: '))

                    if bet > funds:
                        print('Insufficient funds')
                        bet = 0
```

I believe we don't even need to add `end_game` as it is unnecessary in current scope.

These are nested while loop and parent while loop will not break until child breaks. so we need to add extra condition in child while loop which break it on the basis of parent check.

you can read this post [5 Ways To Break Out of Nested Loops in Python](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/5-ways-to-break-out-of-nested-loops-in-python-4c505d34ace7)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue (to Usman's point) really comes from the nesting levels. Basically for the below logic, it will **only** check if play_again is still True once end_game is False, which it will **only** check once funds is no longer > 0.

```
while play_again == 'Y':
  while end_game == False:
    while funds > 0:
      while bet == 0:
        ...
      play_again = input("Play again?")
```

Your code would actually work fine if you had the proper indentation (end of loop being within the "play_again" or "end_game" levels), but unless there's a really good reason, it's typically better to combine conditionals rather than nesting them in multiple while loops that are easy to lose track of. Consider instead:

```
while (play_again == "Y") and (funds > 0):
   if bet == 0:
     bet = int(input('Enter bet amount: '))
   if bet < self.funds:
     print("Insufficient funds")
   ...
```

### Other Notes

Based on the coding style it seems like you're at the start of your wonderful journey into Python, and I wanted to pay forward the help I got starting out by giving some (hopefully) useful tips in case this wasn't part of a structured course. I wound up slapping together an MVP for how this might look below (can build further), please read through the notes though additionally:

- Break apart large functions! It'll make your life a lot easier, this looks to be maybe an initial project and you get a better knack for where to break things up as you move along, but a single function being ~300 lines is just going to make you miserable. General rule of thumb to have maybe 40-50 lines max unless there's a really good reason.
- Utilize classes more (especially if you're trying to be OOP!), a "BlackjackGame" class could help keep methods and attributes organized vs having to set them only once per iteration, and helps keep track of variables across games (i.e. total value).
- Type hinting to make your life easier. Depending on where you are in your learning path this might be a bit later on, but it makes things infinitely easier for working with Intellisense hints (see below using Pylance in VSCode). You could also just create a Deck class itself.
  [image]

#### Sample

```
import itertools
import random
import os
from typing import List, Literal

def clear():
    os.system("clear")

class BlackjackRound:
    def __init__(self, deck):
        self.player_hand: Hand = Hand()
        self.dealer_hand: Hand = Hand()
        self.deck: List[Card] = deck
        
        ## Draw top cards
        for hand in [self.player_hand, self.dealer_hand]:
            for _ in range(2):
                self.deck = hand.draw(self.deck)
        
        self._print_stats()
        while self.player_hand.value < 21:
            choice = input("Enter H to Hit or S to Stand : ")
            if len(choice) != 1 or (choice.upper() != 'H' and choice.upper() != 'S'):
                clear()
                print("Wrong choice!! Try Again")
                continue
            if choice.upper() == 'H':
                self.deck = self.player_hand.draw(self.deck)
            if choice.upper() == 'S':
                break
            self._print_stats()
        ## Resolve Dealer Hand
        self._print_stats(mask_dealer=False)
        while self.dealer_hand.value < 17:
            print("Dealer draws...")
            self.deck = self.dealer_hand.draw(self.deck)
            self._print_stats(mask_dealer=False)
            ##For dramatic tension
            if self.dealer_hand.value < 17:
                input("Enter to continue...")

    def _print_stats(self, mask_dealer=True):
        print("You're hand")
        self.player_hand.print_cards()
        print(f"PLAYER SCORE = {self.player_hand.value}")

        print("Dealer showing...")
        if mask_dealer:
            self.dealer_hand.print_cards(hidden=True, n_cards=1)
            print(f"DEALER SCORE = {self.dealer_hand.cards[0].card_value}")
        else:
            self.dealer_hand.print_cards()
            print(f"DEALER SCORE = {self.dealer_hand.value}")


# The Card class definition
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value, card_value, suit_format):         
        # Suit of the Card like Spades and Clubs
        self.suit = suit
        # Representing Value of the Card like A for Ace, K for King
        self.value = value
        # Score Value for the Card like 10 for King
        self.card_value = card_value
        self.suit_format = suit_format
    #How should Card be printed?
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards: List[Card] = []
        self.value = 0
        
    def draw(self, deck: List[Card]):
        player_card = random.choice(deck)
        self.cards.append(player_card)
        deck.remove(player_card)
        self.value += player_card.card_value
        self.revalue_ace()
        return deck
    
    def revalue_ace(self):
        ##Sum greater than 21, 
        if (self.value > 21) and ("A" in [card.value for card in self.cards]):
            swap_card = list(filter(lambda x: x.value == "A", self.cards))[0]
            self.cards[self.cards.index(swap_card)].card_value = 1
            self.value-=10
        else:
            pass
    
    def print_cards(self, hidden: bool=False, n_cards=None):
        s = ""
        cards = self.cards if n_cards is None else self.cards[0:n_cards]
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t ________________"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t ________________"
        print(s)
    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|                |"    
        print(s)
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            if card.value == '10':
                s = s + "\t|  {}            |".format(card.value)
            else:
                s = s + "\t|  {}             |".format(card.value)  
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|                |"    
        print(s)
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|      * *       |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|    *     *     |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|   *       *    |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|   *       *    |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|       {}        |".format(card.suit_format)
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|          *     |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|         *      |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|        *       |"
        print(s)
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|                |"
        print(s)
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|                |"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|                |"
        print(s)    
    
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            if card.value == '10':
                s = s + "\t|            {}  |".format(card.value)
            else:
                s = s + "\t|            {}   |".format(card.value)
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|        *       |"        
        print(s)    
            
        s = ""
        for card in cards:
            s = s + "\t|________________|"
        if hidden:
            s += "\t|________________|"
        print(s)        
    
        print()
            


class BlackjackGame:
    def __init__(self):
        ##play_again can only be Y/N
        self.play_again: Literal["Y", "N"] = "Y"
        self.player_name: str = input("Player name?: ")
        self.funds = 100
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.ties = 0
        self.blackjacks = 0
        self.busts = 0
    
    def _print_stats(self):
        print(f"Current funds: {self.funds}")
    def play_game(self):
        self._print_stats
        self.shuffle_deck()
        bet = 0
        while (self.play_again == "Y") and (self.funds > 0):
            if bet == 0:
                bet = int(input('Enter bet amount: '))
            if bet < self.funds:
                print("Insufficient funds")
                continue #Restart at the top of the key
            round = BlackjackRound(self.deck)
            if round.player_hand.value == 21:
                print("Blackjack!")
                self.blackjacks+=1
                self.funds+=bet
            elif round.player_hand.value > 21:
                print("BUST")
                self.busts+=1
                self.funds-=bet
            elif round.dealer_hand.value > 21:
                print("DEALER BUST!")
                self.wins +=1
                self.funds+=bet
            elif round.player_hand.value > round.dealer_hand.value:
                print("Win!")
                self.wins+=1
                self.funds+=bet
            elif round.player_hand.value < round.dealer_hand.value:
                print("Lose!")
                self.losses+=1
                self.funds-=bet
            else:
                print("Tie!")
                self.ties+=1
                    ## Error handling for exit
                bet=0
            ##Update deck from round
            self.deck = round.deck
            while True:
                self.play_again = input('Play again(Y/N)?: ')
                if self.play_again == "N":
                    print("So long!")
                    quit()
                elif self.funds == 0:
                    print("Too bad, you're broke!")
                    quit()
                elif self.play_again == "Y":
                    print("Around we go!")
                print("Try again plz")
    
    def shuffle_deck(self,
        suits = {"Spades":"\u2664", "Hearts":"\u2661", "Clubs": "\u2667", "Diamonds": "\u2662"},
        cards = {"A": 11, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}
        ):
        """
        Create a deck of 52 cards
        """
        self.deck = [Card(combo[0], combo[1], cards[combo[1]], suits[combo[0]]) for combo in itertools.product(suits.keys(), cards.keys())]


 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bg = BlackjackGame()
    bg.play_game()
```